# call webservice from different project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

I have two solutions in .net (solution "A" and solution "B") which both have web services. 
I want to call a web service method in solution "B" from solution "A". I am very new to C# and not able to find an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run solution B. then right click on the project on solution A and click add service reference. then when you click discover the service should be visible.

creating one solution and putting both projects in it would make things more simple.

Comment: but is not possible..as i am not going to use all method of Solution B..approx only 4-5 from 40 methods and thanks for quick reply will try

Comment: that shouldnt be a problem you would still be able to add the project in solution B to solution A. but no matter the above should still work.

Answer (score 2):

If both solutions `A` and `B` have web services and you want to use some functionality from web service `B` in `A` you probably should factor out this functionality in a separate class library project that you can then use in both `A` and `B` (used internally by the web services to provide their functionality).

This also will benefit your project long term, especially the testability aspect.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new webservice in Solution B and add the required method in newly created webservice from existing service and then follow the steps provided by the Marcom.